# Visualizing distributions of start and stop dates/times

Tags: data-visualization

I am looking for good ways to visualize the distribution (by group) of durations of events measured by start and stop dates (or times).

For example, let's say I am interested in visualizing life spans of two cohorts.

```
#  example data -- not intended to be realistic
n <- 5e3; set.seed(123)
vets <- data.frame(conflict = c(rep('WWII',2*n/3), rep('Vietnam',n/3)),
                       birth_date = c(as.Date(rnorm(2*n/3, sd=500), 
                                              origin = "1923-01-01"),
                                      as.Date(rnorm(n/3, sd=400), 
                                              origin = "1949-01-01")) )
vets$death_date = vets$birth_date + c(rnorm(2*n/3, mean=68*365, sd=14*365),
                                      rnorm(n/3, mean=70*365, sd=15*365))

vets <- vets[with(vets, order(conflict, birth_date, death_date)),]
vets$index <- 1:nrow(vets)
```

I have tried something like:

```
ggplot(vets, aes(y=index, yend=index)) + 
  geom_segment( data=vets, aes(x=birth_date, xend=death_date, col=conflict) ) + 
  xlab('Life Span') + ylab(NULL) +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y=element_blank())
```

Which makes either the start date or end date distribution unclear (depending on which one I sort by):

[image]

And then I tried simplifying the durations to average rectangles, with error bars at the ends:

```
mean_birth <- as.Date(tapply(vets$birth_date, INDEX = vets$conflict, FUN=mean), 
                      origin='1970-01-01')
sd_birth  <- tapply(vets$birth_date, INDEX = vets$conflict, FUN=sd)
mean_death <- as.Date(tapply(vets$death_date, INDEX = vets$conflict, FUN=mean), 
                      origin='1970-01-01')
sd_death  <- tapply(vets$death_date, INDEX = vets$conflict, FUN=sd)
min_index <- tapply(vets$index, INDEX = vets$conflict, FUN=min)
max_index <- tapply(vets$index, INDEX = vets$conflict, FUN=max)
mean_index <- tapply(vets$index, INDEX = vets$conflict, FUN=mean)

vets_summ <- data.frame(conflict = names(mean_birth), 
                        count = as.numeric(with(vets, table(conflict))),
                        mean_birth, sd_birth, mean_death, sd_death,
                        min_index, max_index, mean_index)

ggplot(vets_summ, aes(xmin=mean_birth, xmax=mean_death,
                      fill=conflict, ymin=min_index, 
                      ymax=max_index, y=mean_index, height=count/2))+ 
  geom_rect()+ 
  xlab('Life Span') + ylab(NULL) +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y=element_blank()) + 
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = mean_birth - 1.96 * sd_birth,
                     xmax = mean_birth + 1.96 * sd_birth,
                     x = mean_birth), col = 'navy blue') +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = mean_death - 1.96 * sd_death,
                     xmax = mean_death + 1.96 * sd_death,
                     x = mean_death), col = 'navy blue')
```

[image]

And I could combine the approaches by adding error bars to the first plot.

What are some good approaches for visualizing this type of data?  Are there any well-known examples?

**edit:**  removing the R tag since this is not an R programming question.  A solution on a bar napkin is helpful.

Comment: Old question, but if you're still interested: What about boxplots showing the lifespan of each cohort? It's akin to the "average rectangles" visualization, except that you lose the birth and death years. But do you really need these two information? You already know that Vietnam War veterans were not born in the 1920s, and boxplots are a common visualization method. Here's what it would look like: https://imgur.com/a/nUuFCOR

Comment: Besides boxplots (or possibly density plots), a line plot of "Age" vs "Life-Year" is a possible alternative. Here is an example p. 23 of this document, which compares data from various cohorts of veterans, including WW2 and Vietnam war: https://www.va.gov/vetdata/docs/SpecialReports/Mortality_study_USVETS_1980_2017.pdf . But it depends on what we want to show exactly, which unfortunately is a bit unclear from the question asked. But hopefully it might be useful to someone else.